# Feed Javascript directly into RequireJS Require function

Tags: requirejs, amd

We have require implemented in our web app and is working a treat. The change up now is that we have some javascript that is dynamically created at runtime on the client. Is there a way with require to directly inject a string of javascript directly into the require() function.

Currently we have:

```
 require([moduleToLoad], function(mod){ //DO SOMETHING}});
```

Want something like (forgive the syntax because just writing it out):

```
var jsString = "define(['Text!something.htm'], function (control_Template) { //MODULE LOADED JAVASCRIPT}))";
require(jsString, function(mod){ //DO SOMETHING}});
```

Does anyone know how and if we can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you control at all how `jsString` is constructed? Are you going to be passing `jsString` around and call `require(jsString, ...` multiple times in different places?

Comment: Try naming the module. And then run it by doing eval `eval("define('runtimemodule', ['Text!something.htm'], func.....` and then `require(["runtimemodule"], function(mod))`. Not sure if this will work but you will at least need this...

Comment: I woner in what case you require this. Only case I can think of is you have the code generated on the client side and it need to be shared with some  other AMD modules.. but I think there should be a better way to do what you are trying to do than doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named modules syntax in your string for defining the AMD module. Eval this string and then require the module using the name you have provided.

Define module like following

```
eval("define('runtimemodule', ['Text!something.htm'], function(){ return 'template here' })")
```

Require module like following

```
require(["runtimemodule"], function(mod){ 
   console.log(mod); //logs "tempalte here"
});
```